# Как получить файл по прямой ссылке

Tags: python

У меня скрипт, написанный на Python, который разбирает .csv файл, анализирует его, строит отчет и записывает результат в .xlsx файл. Неудобство было в том, что анализируемый файл приходится выгружать из админки самостоятельно, поэтому я решил его выгружать с помощью GET запроса, но так как я всего месяц изучаю программирование, то видимо не понял суть запроса.

```
import requests
res = requests.get('https://domain.ru/bitrix/admin/iblock_element_admin.php?PAGEN_1=1&SIZEN_1=20&mode=excel&type=messages&IBLOCK_ID=97&lang=ru&set_filter=Y&adm_filter_applied=0&find_el=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80&find_el_type=name&find_el_timestamp_from_FILTER_PERIOD=interval&find_el_timestamp_from_FILTER_DIRECTION=previous&find_el_timestamp_from=18.11.2019&find_el_timestamp_to=20.11.2019&find_el_created_from_FILTER_DIRECTION=previous')
```

Ссылка показана для пример. В обычном сценарии при установке этой ссылки в адресную строку формируется файл с отчетом, который меня интересует, я думал, что алгоритм перейдет по этой ссылке и файл сформируется автоматически, но этого не происходит. Я понимаю, что ссылку лучше формировать через param, но проблема, думаю, не в этом.

Хотелось бы узнать:

- Почему не формируется файл?
- Как мне с помощью скрипта Python получить выгрузку?

Comment: А что происходит? Просто переход по ссылке без скачивания файла?

Comment: Если та ссылка активирует редирект к файлу, то можно узнать ссылку после редиректа через `res.url`

Comment: Ну так ты получаешь содержимое файла в ответе сервера, просто сохрани его на диск, а-ля `with open('file.csv') as fp: fp.write(res.content)`, дальше работай с файлом `file.csv`, ну или просто парси содержимое напрямую, а-ля `parsed = csv.parser(res.content)` и т.д.

Comment: Привет! Думаю, проблема в том, что в админке битрикса надо залогиниться, а requests пытается скачать файл как ноунейм, отчего ему Bitrix ссылку и не дает. Проверь `res.status_code`, возможно он 403 (доступ запрещен).

Comment: @Oskar Sharipov специально заранее залогинился, res.status_code отдал 200. По идее все ок

Comment: @Василиса именно так

Comment: @gil9red  спасибо за советы сегодня попробую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ну так ты получаешь содержимое файла в ответе сервера, просто сохрани его на диск, а-ля with open('file.csv') as fp: fp.write(res.content), дальше работай с файлом file.csv, ну или просто парси содержимое напрямую, а-ля parsed = csv.parser(res.content) и т.д. – hoefling 21 ноя в 20:55

Это совершенно верный ответ. Спасибо  hoefling